# Alpha Numeric with Underscores Regex Pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm extending the CodeIgniter Form Validation library to check for Alpha Numeric values with underscores **excluding dashes**. But I'm very new to regex patterns and would like some help...

Currently for alpha_numeric CI has:

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

And for alpha_dash CI has:

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9_-])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

And I'm creating 'alpha_underscore' (which again will be alpha numeric with underscores):

Is this correct?

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9_])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

I am confused as to why there is a '-' at the beginning and end of the 'alpha_dash' pattern

Comment: both answers were correct, but I picked codaddict's (which I read Call of Duty Addict) b/c it was clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character class `[-a-z0-9_-]` is same as `[a-z0-9_-]` or `[-a-z0-9_]`.

One of the `-` can be dropped.

Answer (score 3):

The character was just duplicated. You can remove one instance of it and the regex should work fine.

Comment: So to clarify, the '-' was duplicated in the 'alpha_dash' pattern and my regex is fine?